# Publish on facebook wall from c/c++ or linux

Tags: c++, c, facebook-graph-api, curl

Can anybody point out a method to publish on my Facebook wall from a C program (without using any non-standard libraries; curl is OK! ).

If none are known/available, could you at least propose a solution from a bash shell (so I can use it with c `system()`). I found some on the internet, but none of them use the new Facebook graph API.

Answer (score 3):

Once you granted `publish_stream` permission to application you can do something like this to create posts in user's feed (wall) from **C**

```
curl = curl_easy_init();

char *data="message=Posting from C&";
strcat(data, "link=http://placekitten.com&");
strcat(data, "picture=http://placekitten.com/90/90&");
strcat(data, "name=Meow&");
strcat(data, "caption={*actor*} places kittens on the wall&");
strcat(data, "description=Some description&");
strcat(data, "access_token=USER_OR_APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed");
/* Disable SSL check (only for testing) */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_easy_perform(curl); /* post */
```

Graph API is really simple you should read [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for more info, in your case you may want to read some additional details about [posting in feed](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts)

Comment: how do I grant permission? I cannot find this

Comment: You can do this in couple of ways. You can read about it on [Authorization](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) documentation. Consider reading some other questions on subject or asking it as separate question.

Comment: Problem solved. BTW I think there is a bug in your C code. You don't allocate enough memory for the variable data to do strcat's.